# ExpressJS cannot get POST

Tags: node.js, express

The relevant part of my `app.js` is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var routes = require('./config/routes);
app.use('/', routes);
```

My route file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var upgradesController = require('../../app/controllers/upgrades.server.controller');

// This should receive POST requests
router.post('/api/upgrades/device', upgradesController.create);

module.exports = router;
```

And finally my controller is

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
}
```

But this sends nothing. It's always an empty JSON value. I'm using PostMan for testing:

[image]
What is happening?

Comment: Considering it responds with the request's body, you'd need to show us what you're actually sending.

Comment: I'm just using Postman to send some data. See image above; I've updated my answer.

Comment: When I send JSON to my API using Postman I need to send the data using the "raw" option and then select "JSON" from the dropdown so the "application/json" header is sent.  Not sure if that's your issue but might be worth testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending form-data, switch to x-www-form-urlencoded instead. You can also send "raw", and input valid JSON.

Comment: Wow thanks. Can't believe it was that simple! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can